# Reemplazar comas por puntos en un dataframe (coma como separador decimal)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-2.x

Soy nuevo en pandas y tengo una duda relacionada con cambiar puntos por comas en  Python 2.

Los números en el csv se presentan de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen los flotantes tienen diferente cantidad de decimales.

Primero intente cambiarlos de la clásica forma en Calc y Excel con "buscar y reemplazar" pero sucedía esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para los números con tres decimales no les reemplazaba la coma por un punto si no que borraba la coma y los dejaba como un entero.

Luego intente en Python con la librería Pandas, con estos comandos:

```
comas_por_puntos = [float(x.replace(',','.')) for x in bd_df['col_1']]
col_1.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)
```

Al mostrar `col_1` (convertido en DataFrame) con un `print`, se veía todo bien, exporte el DataFrame a csv pero al abrirlo me encontré con la misma situación de la imagen anterior, es decir no había punto en los números con tres decimales.

También intente quitándole un decimal a los que tenían cuatro, pero el resultado era el mismo.

Cuando le agregaba a mano un decimal a los de tres si se cambiaba bien, pero resulta que son muchas filas.

¿A qué se deberá esto?

También se me ocurre recorrer la columnas del DataFrame y agregar un decimal a los de tres pero no sé como hacer eso...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si los datos los lees de un csv con `pandas.read_csv` y el uso de la coma como separador decimal es consistente en todo el archivo, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente usar el parámetro `decimal` que permite especificar cuál es el carácter usado como punto decimal:

```
import io 
import pandas as pd

csv = io.StringIO(
u'''col_1;col_2
7,477;a
7,4848;b
7,4;c
7,5126;d
7,5029;e
5;f''')   




bd_df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", decimal=",")
```

El uso de `io.StringIO` es solo para simular un `.csv` y hacer un ejemplo reproducible. En cualquier caso lo que se usaría en lugar de `csv` es la ruta al fichero:

```
bd_df = pd.read_csv("ruta/al/fichero.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")
```

Con lo que obtenemos lo buscado:

> ```
> >>> bd_df
>     col_1  col_2
> 0  7.4770      a
> 1  7.4848      b
> 2  7.4000      c
> 3  7.5126      d
> 4  7.5029      e
> 5  5.0000      f
>
>
> >>> bd_df.dtypes
> col_1    float64
> col_2     object
> dtype: object
> ```

Si quieres guardar el csv de nuevo usando el punto como separador decimal, no hay problema, si deseas que tus columnas tengan un número x  de decimales puedes usar `float_format`:

```
bd_df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=True,
              decimal='.', sep=',', float_format='%.4f')
```

con lo que obtenemos el siguiente fichero csv:

> col_1,col_2
>   7.4770,a
>   7.4848,b
>   7.4000,c
>   7.5126,d
>   7.5029,e
>   5.0000,f

Si no fuera posible lo anterior (por ejemplo se usa . en todas las columnas pero no en una) puedes usar `pandas.Series.str.replace`:

```
bd_df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";")
bd_df['col_1'] = bd_df['col_1'].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
```

> **Nota**: `pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects` está marcado como "deprecated" desde la versión 0.18, en favor de `pandas.DataFrame.to_*` (p.e `pandas.DataFrame.to_numeric`)

Answer (score 0):

FJSevilla

Me ha sido de mucha ayuda el saber agregar los parámetros al exportar como me los indicastes, con eso, más este comando:

```
comas_por_puntos = [float(x.replace(',','.')) for x in bd_df['col_1']]
```

se solucionó el problema.

La primera alternativa también la probé, pero creo que falta una "u" antes de :
'''F;S, porque eso lanza un error que logré corregir buscando el error y me sugería ponerlo asi ---> u'''F;S,...
Pero no pude resolver el problema con esa solución.
Pude hacer que me exportara como quería pero solo para los que se indica en el código que escribiste:

```
csv = io.StringIO(
'''F;S
7,477;a
7,4848;b
7,4;c
7,5126;d
7,5029;e
5;f''')
```

Porque en el csv tengo cerca de 1900 filasy me parecio extraño tener que agregarle una letra.
Pero en fin la solución apreció gracias a ti.
Saludos.

Comment: Juan es un error tonto mio lo que comentas (corregido).No vi lo de Python 2... Efectivamente mi ejemplo falla porque `StringIO` espera una cadena no bytes que es lo que realmente es `str` en Python 2 (en Python 3 es UTF-8), al usar `u""` indicas que es un literal unicode. La otra opción es usar `BytesIO`. De cualquier forma el código en si funciona en Python 2 sin problemas, si no es así agrega en error a ver si damos con lo que es, la primera opción es la más directa y la más eficiente (parcer en C), en Pandas/NumPy evita siempre que puedas los ciclos y llamadas a funciones Python. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

`datos = pd.read_excel(ruta)`

Ver la columna números con tres decimales, separador de miles "." separador de decimales ",":

`datos[números] = datos[números].map('{:,.2f}€'.format).str.replace(",", "~").str.replace(".", ",") .str.replace("~", ".")`

Ver la columna con los números con dos decimales y el símbolos de euros

`datos[números] = datos[números].map('{:,.2f}€'.format).str.replace(",", "~").str.replace(".", ",") .str.replace("~", ".")`